# ViewModel doesn´t retains data when screen rotation

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I am putting myself in a RecycleView from Java to Kotlin. I am trying to keep state between screen rotations. But it is not working. Here my code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
//import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*




class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: ScoreViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory().create(ScoreViewModel::class.java)

        //viewModel  = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ScoreViewModel::class.java)

        println("-> "+viewModel.scoreTeamA);
    }

    fun addOneForTeamA(view: View) {
        viewModel.scoreTeamA++
        displayForTeamA()
    }
    fun addTwoForTeamA(view: View) {
        viewModel.scoreTeamA += 2
        displayForTeamA()
    }
    fun addThreeForTeamA(view: View) {
        viewModel.scoreTeamA += 3
        displayForTeamA()
    }
    fun addOneForTeamB(view: View) {
        ++viewModel.scoreTeamB
        displayForTeamB()
    }
    fun addTwoForTeamB(view: View) {
        viewModel.scoreTeamB += 2
        displayForTeamB()
    }
    fun addThreeForTeamB(view: View) {
        viewModel.scoreTeamB += 3
        displayForTeamB()
    }

    fun displayForTeamA(){
        team_a_score.text = viewModel.scoreTeamA.toString()
    }

    fun displayForTeamB(){
        team_b_score.text = viewModel.scoreTeamB.toString()
    }

    fun resetScore(view: View) {
        viewModel.scoreTeamA = 0
        viewModel.scoreTeamB = 0
        displayForTeamA()
        displayForTeamB()
    }

}




import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel


class ScoreViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var scoreTeamA: Int = 0
    var scoreTeamB: Int = 0


}
```

Another question is why in one project ViewModelProviders.of appears as deprecated (se  commented lines) and in another project with similar gradle dependencies it is OK.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Using `ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory().create` is going to create a new instance each time - this is never the right thing to use. Instead, follow the [ViewModelProviders.of() deprecation message](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders#of(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity)):

> Use the `by viewModels()` Kotlin property delegate or [`ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider#ViewModelProvider(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner)), passing in the activity.

```
viewModel  = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ScoreViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is useful, sadly I haven't enough score to give you my point. Any case, using lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0 I was able to use ViewModelProviders.of but ViewModel didn't retained state. By the way, following your links to Android API docs, there is not information about which version of library it is talking about. So, is very tricky to know which library versions to use. In this case 2.2.0 haven't ViewModelProviders but 2.1.0 has.

Comment: The first thing you should do is upgrade to the latest stable version of each library - that's what has the correct behavior and the `ViewModelProvider` constructor that you want to use.